Jointly Testing a Composite Null
Suppose we have a GLM with $g^{-1}(\mathbb{E}[y|x]) = \beta_0+x_A\beta_A+x_b\beta_B$. I would like to test the following hypotheses: $H_0: \beta_A \leq 0 \cup\beta_B\leq0$ $H_1: \beta_A>0\cap \beta_B>0$. Could someone point me in the right direction regarding a construction of a test that leads to a valid p-value in these situations? If I am not wrong, I am testing two composite null hypotheses, but I don't know what else to do with that information.

I have seen these tests in the context of pleiotropy in genetics. They are relatively complicated because of the 'corner' in the null hypothesis at $(0,0)$.  The null distribution depends on where in the null hypothesis you are.  Life would be simpler if you were willing to be Bayesian and could just work with the posterior probability that $\beta_A>0$ and $\beta_B>0$.
Life would be slightly simpler even if you switched $H_1$ and $H_0$: the likelihood ratio test for a convex corner null is a mixture of $\chi^2_2$, $\chi^2_1$ and $\chi^2_0$ distributions, where the mixing proportions depend on the correlation of the $\hat\beta$s.
For a concave corner null the distribution of your test statistic is going to depend on where in the null you are.   You are unlikely to do much better than doing two separate tests for $\beta_A\leq 0$ and $\beta_B\leq B$ and rejecting $H_0$ if both tests reject.   This test is conservative when $(\beta_A,\beta_B)\approx (0,0)$, but you can't know that $(\beta_A,\beta_B)\approx (0,0)$ without using up information.

Thank you. I did consider a Bayesian solution to this problem as well, and I will proceed with that instead. Do you have any references for understanding this kind of corner phenomenon?

There's a book Order Restricted Statistical Inference from the late 1980s, if you can find it.   This paper by Self & Liang is a good start: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/763-2015/week06/papers/self-liang-1987.pdf
